# MongoDB: No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoDB (version 2.2.36) in Nodejs. The problem is when I try to use array update there is an error "No array filter found for identifier 'rival' in path ...", but when I try it in mongo shell everything is ok.
Code in nodejs:

```
db.get().collection(collectionName).update({ _id: ObjectID(id) }, {$inc: {
        "votesCount": 1,
        "rivals.$[rival].votes": 1
    },
}, { arrayFilters: [{ "rival.id": voteModel.answerId }]}, function (err, docs) {
    cb(err, docs);
});
```

I try to update the version, but 2.2.36 is the latest.

Comment: You are expclicitly converting the `id` to and ObjectID, do you need to do the same with `answerId`?

Comment: The answerId is generated in front end, this is not a mongo id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MongoDB Node.JS driver version 2.2.36 doesn't have array filter support in the [update method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#update).

Starting in version 3.0 [update](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#update) does have the arrayFilters option.

You'll need to upgrade the driver in order to use that option.

Comment: There was a problem when I update mongodb to 3.5.9 version, but now everything is ok, thanks.